# Como declarar um input de senha(password)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber se há como mascarar a entrada de caracteres no `input()` do python.

Ex:

```
Senha = 1234

Entrada = int(input("Digite sua senha: "))
```

Na entrada acima eu queria trocar as letras introduzidas por asteriscos.

Há como fazer isso em python?

Comment: Na realidade, usar o getpass não troca as letras inseridas por astericos. O que ele faz é ocultar os dígitos de sua senha, que na minha opinião, é mais seguro do que exibir os asteriscos, pois você não expõe a quantidade de caracteres de sua senha. Exemplo: import getpass senha = getpass.getpass('Informe sua senha: ') print(senha) > Informe sua senha: > 1234

Comment: Na programação você pode escrever isso manualmente e fazer a substituição dos dados por o caractere asterisco.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar o módulo "getpass".

```
import getpass
senha = getpass.getpass("Digite sua senha: ")
```

Ele irá mostrar asteriscos ao digitar a senha.

Comment: Isso mesmo - o getpass é bem elaborado, e feito pra isso (e vem junto com o Python).